# Mono for Android Dialog box

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I'm using mono for android and I'm trying to figure out how to add a dialog box after every 100 clicks of a button, the code looks something like this the program will already count every click of the button. I was thinking an if statement?

```
button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };

if(count >= 5)

            {                
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.SetMessage("Your On Your Way");
                builder.SetCancelable(false);
                builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { });
                var dialog = builder.Create();
                dialog.Show();

            }
```

Comment: Seems fine, but should be part of the anonymous function and you probably need condition like ``count%100 == 0``.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the if statement inside your button's delegate:

```
button.Click += delegate
            {
                button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);

                if (count % 100 == 0)
                {
                    var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.SetMessage("Your On Your Way");
                    builder.SetCancelable(false);
                    builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { });
                    builder.Show();
                }

            };
```